# nothing is drawn on page using javascript and canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to develop a game and i am starting to dip my toes into the HTML `<canvas>` tag and using it with javascript. My program here is my work in progress clone of PONG. I have managed to add the two paddles with no error but as i have added the Ball function it simply refuses to draw anything on the screen and thus i am given a page covered in black.

Could it be because i am using classes?

**Here is the code:**

```js
// ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)';
// ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 5;
var dy = 5;

//Class Definitions
function Game(width, height, colour) {
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.colour = colour;
}

function Player(width, height, colour, x, y, up, down) {
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.colour = colour;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.up = up;
 this.down = down;
 this.move = function(ny) {
  this.y = this.y + ny;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    
 };
}

function Ball(width, height, colour, x , y, isTouched, isInGoal) {
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;
 this.colour = colour;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.isTouched = isTouched;
 this.isInGoal = isInGoal;
 this.move = function() {
  clear();
  this.x = this.x + 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
 };
}

//Creating new Classes

var gameStage = new Game((window.innerWidth), (window.innerHeight), 'rgb(0,0,0)');
var paddleOne = new Player(10, 150, 'rgb(255,255,255)', (gameStage.width/10), (gameStage.height/2), 38, 40);
var paddleTwo = new Player(10, 150, 'rgb(255,255,255)', (gameStage.width/1.1), (gameStage.height/2), 87, 83);
var ball = new Ball(20, 20, 'rgb(255,255,255)', (gameStage.width/2), (gameStage.height/2), 0, 0);

//Initialisation

function init(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('game');
 canvas.setAttribute('width', gameStage.width);
 canvas.setAttribute('height', gameStage.height);
 canvas.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
 if (game.getContext){
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  return setInterval(ball.move, 10);
  return setInterval(draw, 10);
 }

}

//Canvas Functions

function clear(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameStage.width, gameStage.height);
}

function draw() {
 clear();
 ctx.fillStyle = gameStage.colour;
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, gameStage.width, gameStage.height);
  
 ctx.fillStyle = paddleOne.colour;
 ctx.fillRect(paddleOne.x, paddleOne.y, paddleOne.width, paddleOne.height);

 ctx.fillStyle = paddleTwo.colour;
 ctx.fillRect(paddleTwo.x, paddleTwo.y, paddleTwo.width, paddleTwo.height);

 console.log("PlayerOne Y Coordinate: " + paddleOne.y + "\n");
 console.log("PlayerTwo Y Coordinate: " + paddleTwo.y + "\n");
}

//Player Control

function doKeyDown(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == paddleOne.up){
  paddleOne.move(-5);
 } else if (e.keyCode == paddleOne.down) {
  paddleOne.move(5);
 } else if (e.keyCode == paddleTwo.up) {
  paddleTwo.move(-5);
 } else if (e.keyCode == paddleTwo.down) {
  paddleTwo.move(5);
 }
}

//For HTML

function beginStuff(){
 init();
 window.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
}
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body, html {height: 100%;}


#game {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<htmL>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>A game</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body onload="beginStuff();" >
    <canvas id="game">
      Please upgrade your browser to support HTML5. <br/>
    </canvas>
  </body>
</htmL>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @skirtle, i moved the `ball.move();` to the `draw()` function and removed the `clear()` call from the `ball.move()` function.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong to me:

```
return setInterval(ball.move, 10);
return setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Firstly, you've got 2 returns. Secondly, you've lost the binding on the `move` method:

```
return setInterval(ball.move.bind(ball), 10);
```

If that doesn't fix it I suggest stepping through in a debugger, line-by-line, making sure that everything is doing exactly what you expect it to.

Comment: implemented your binding return stuff, the ball those what it is supposed to do but paddles do not appear. If i hold down up or down the left paddle flashes and moves & vice versa for the right paddle. How do i fix this?

Comment: @QuerkyBren You need to redraw everything after you clear the canvas. Currently, after you call `clear` you're drawing either the paddles or the ball, not both.